# Blackjack Program with Hit() method

Tags: java

I have this class called card-set that holds the array-list for my cards

---

```
public abstract class CardSet {

    public ArrayList<Card> cards;
    public Card card = new Card();
    private int cardSize;

    public CardSet(int cardSize) {
        this.cardSize = cardSize;
    }
    public CardSet() {};


    public abstract void displayAllCards();
    public abstract void displayVisibleCards();


}
```

Enum with all my suits

```
public enum Suit {

    CLUBS,
    DIAMONDS,
    HEARTS,
    SPADES
}
```

The deck class that populates the deck with 52 cards

```
public class Deck extends CardSet {

    private final int SIZE = 52;

    public Deck() {
        populateDeck();
        shuffle();
        draw();

    }

    public void populateDeck() {
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            for (int a = 0; a <= 3; a++) {
                for (int b = 0; b <= 12; b++) {
                    cards.add(new Card(a, b));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void shuffle() {
        Collections.shuffle(cards);
    }

    public void draw() {//ie taking one from the top of the deck
        cards.remove(0);
    }

    public int size() {
        return this.SIZE;
    }

    public void displayCards(int start) {
        System.out.println(cards.get(start));
    }
    public void displayAllCards() {
        for(Card i : cards) {
            System.out.println(i + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

My problem here is I'm not sure how to add 1 card each time per hit, or how I can just make seperate hands for my program. I'm really new at this.

```
public class Hand extends CardSet {

    private String userName;

    public ArrayList<Card> cardsInHand;

    /**
     * 
     * @param userName
     */
    public Hand(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public String getUserName() {
        return this.userName;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param userName
     */
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public void hit(Card c) {
        cardsInHand.add(cards.get(0));
    }

    public int getCardValue(Card c) {
        return c.getRank();
    }
}
```

GameOf21:

```
public class GameOf21 {

    Deck deck;
    Hand user;
    Hand computer;


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public GameOf21(String name) {
        deck = new Deck();
        user = new Hand(name);
        computer = new Hand("Computer");
    }

    public void playGame() {
        System.out.println("The deck has " + deck.size() + " cards");

        System.out.println("*********" + user + "********");
        user.hit();
    }

    public String printTitle() {
        return "This application allows a player to play the game of "
                + "\n21 against the computer.";
    }
}
```

the class where the game starts to be played

```
public class GameOf21App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = " ";
        GameOf21 g = new GameOf21(name);
        System.out.println(g.printTitle() + "\n" );
        System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
        name = g.input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Game of 21 " + name + "\n");

        g.playGame();
    }
}
```

This Program is supposed to just simulate a game of 21 against a *computer*. Each players hands are populated with 2 cards, and the option to hit at the end. If it goes over 21, whoever went over loses. etc you all know how to play.

My issue lies within the `hand.hit()` method, I can't figure out how to properly add a value from my deck into the hand. It's just **not clicking** with me, *any help is appreciated.*

Comment: What have you tried? Do you need something more special than `cardsInHand.add(newCard)`?

Comment: The thing with that is card accepts int,int, or suit int. But I've already created and populated a deck with all of those, I'm just trying to get the first card on the deck and add it to my users hand.